# create method is raising key error in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API for signup.

Serializers.py

```
class UserSignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'role']
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def create(self, validate_data):

    user = User.objects.create(email=validate_data['email'], first_name=validate_data['first_name'],last_name=validate_data['last_name'], role='user', username=validate_data['username'])
    user.set_password(validate_data['password'])

    user.save()
    return user
```

Views.py

```
class UserSignupView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSignupSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

But this is giving key error 'email' or anything I put first in this line:

```
user = User.objects.create(email=validate_data['email'], first_name=validate_data['first_name'],last_name=validate_data['last_name'], role='user', username=validate_data['username'])
```

**Edit**
Error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/user_signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 457, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 468, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\FitnessProject\FitnessApp\fitness_api\views.py", line 187, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 213, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "D:\Django\FitnessProject\FitnessApp\fitness_api\serializers.py", line 85, in create
    user = User.objects.create(email=validate_data['email'], first_name=validate_data['first_name'],last_name=validate_data['last_name'], role='user', username=validate_data['username'])
KeyError: 'email'
[2019-09-03 11:49:43,186] log: ERROR - Internal Server Error: /api/user_signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 457, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 468, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\FitnessProject\FitnessApp\fitness_api\views.py", line 187, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "D:\django\FitnessProject\fitness_venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 213, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "D:\Django\FitnessProject\FitnessApp\fitness_api\serializers.py", line 85, in create
    user = User.objects.create(email=validate_data['email'], first_name=validate_data['first_name'],last_name=validate_data['last_name'], role='user', username=validate_data['username'])
KeyError: 'email'
[03/Sep/2019 11:49:43] "POST /api/user_signup/?username=user_4&last_name=user&first_name=user&email=u@gmail.com&password=user&role=user HTTP/1.1" 500 18553
```

Comment: Keyerror 'email' denotes that `validate_data` doesn't have a key 'email' check printing your **dict**, so that you can put appropriate key value

Comment: printed dictionary: UserSignupSerializer(data=<QueryDict: {'username': ['use_4'], 'first_name': ['ghh'], 'last_name': ['hjgjh'], 'email': ['hgj@gmail.com'], 'role': ['user'], 'password': ['ghvhg']}>):

Comment: please, show full stack of the error.

Comment: The **dict** you printed is `UserSignupSerializer` but what you used and got error was `validate_data`. Check with that.

Comment: this dict is validate_data. I used print(validate_data)

Comment: I think the `data` key is containing the entire **dict**, so try printing `validate_data['data']`, if that works, then you can use `.create(...validate_data['data']['email']...)`

Comment: can you also add `print (serializer.validated_data)` after `if serializer.is_valid():` and show us.

Comment: @amrs-tech validate_data['data'] is printing key error 'data'

Comment: @BearBrown print (serializer.validated_data) is printing OrderedDict()

Comment: And validate data is not a dictionary. when I print validate_data.keys(). It printed nothing. just dict_keys([])

Comment: I think then you should try create with the value from respective model objects `UserSignupSerializer`. But I'm sorry even if this didn't work

Comment: Inherit from `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.Serializer`

Comment: @ArpitSvt, thanks brother to observe this. This was result of blind copy paste. problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use *serializers.Modelserializer* instead of *serializers.Serializer*.